# memory leaks in Corona Apps

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, coronasdk

I have released all the display objects and my every scene got destroyed after executing. I have multiple screens in app and I am using storyboard for transactions. When I made transaction from one to another very slightly memory usage increased, but if I run my app for a long time , it starts hanging and sometimes respond very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen to you running the storyboard sample? If so, you should file a bug report and consider using Director as an alternative in the meantime. If not you should carefully review your code to ensure you are properly disposing of sprite sheets, audio, etc. and that you aren't using globals.

Comment: yes, I am using storyboard. My project is huge almost 20 screens. I carefully dispose the everything and ain't using global. If at this stage I change to Director , it will be a big issue and take a much time.

Comment: One more thing, since my project is quite big so is there some alternative to find the memory leaks?